# Duvida sobre Select

Tags: java, mysql

Olá, estou fazendo uma verificação de usuário/senha em java e preciso realizar uma consulta em que verifique no banco de há um login e uma senha referente ao digitado nas `jTextFields`. Porém não estou conseguindo se alguém puder me ajudar fico agradecido, para ajudar a ter uma noção do que eu preciso aqui vai um exemplo :

```
sql= "SELECT * FROM login_sistema WHERE usuario_login =(aqui no caso ficaria a variavel do jTextField) AND senha_login =(aqui no caso ficaria a variável do jTextField) ";
```

Porém não sei como implementar no campo demarcado a variável contendo o valor do `textField` tentei de varias maneiras porém só resultou erro.

Comment: Veja se não esqueceu das "'". Teu código deveria ficar assim: "SELECT * FROM login_sistema WHERE usuario_login ='(aqui no caso ficaria a variavel do jTextField)' AND senha_login ='(aqui no caso ficaria a variavel do jTextField)'";

Comment: Mas por exemplo, eu adicionei os jTextFields a uma variavel desta maneira [ String senha_conf = jTextField2.getText(); ] como eu poderia incluir a variavel senha_conf no codigo sql ?

Comment: Está usando jdbc? se tiver  o código que processa a sql coloque também

Comment: Sim, estou. 
            PreparedStatement ps;
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps = (PreparedStatement) ps.executeQuery(sql); 
            ps.setString(1, login_login);  
            ps.setString(2, senha_senha);

Comment: isto é oque estou colocando depois da requisição sql

Comment: Acho que só faltou as interrogações e postar o seu código na pergunta :P, parte dele parece correto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize prepared statements para definir os valores da sua consulta, depois mande a consulta para o banco com `executeQuery()` e pegue o retorno e por último faça um while para pegar os resultados.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM login_sistema WHERE usuario_login = ? AND senha_login = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString(1,   jTextField_login);
stmt.setString(2,   jTextField_senha);      

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

while (rs.next()) {
        String login = rs.getString("username");
        String senha = rs.getString("senha");
        system.out.println("Login: "+login +" Senha: "+senha);
}
```